# Copy specific columns from one hidden sheet to another sheet with VBA, destination order is also specific order

Tags: excel, vba

I've been looking for a solution to this for some time now. 
Excel 2016/365, Win 10, both x64.

I have a Sheet "Temp" It is a hidden sheet and does not need to ever be seen. The data is pasted to it with a button on a Worksheet, from the Windows clipboard. 
The "Temp" sheet need not exist except for executing the task it's needed for.
I then have code to copy specific columns by their name to another sheet "Analyse" after which "Temp" is cleared completely. Can be deleted too and recreated when needed as an option.

The problem with my code.
It looks for the columns by column name and copies them to the destination as needed, however the source columns in "Temp" is not always in the same order.
Example 1: Date, Column 2, Type, Column 4, Color, Column 6, Something
Example 2: Type, Column 2, Date, Color, Column 5, Column 6, Something

When looking for these columns they are found but copied in the order they are found. Not the order that the destination is in.

Destination sheet "Analyse" also has column headers in place.
Example: Date, Type, Color, Something, Formula1, Formula2, Formula3
The Formula columns have lookup values based on some of the other columns. I need to fill those formulas with VBA too, but that can wait.

I have been trying to re-write what I have using what others have tried, but have gotten stuck.
Here's what I have. There is more that does other stuff, but this portion is where I need help.

```
Sub PasteFromClipboard()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Temp").Visible = True

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Sheets("Temp").Cells.ClearContents
    Sheets("Temp").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets("Temp").Activate

    RenameColumnNames
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Temp").Visible = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Sheets("Search").Activate
    MsgBox "Paste sucessful, Please click Analyse."


Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
MsgBox "Nothing to paste!"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Temp").Visible = False
Sheets("Search").Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub

End Sub

Sub Analyse() 'Excel VBA to move Columns based on criteria

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ar As Variant, i As Long, rng As Range, shTemp As Worksheet, shAnal As Worksheet

Set shTemp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Temp")
Set shAnal = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Analyse")
shTemp.Visible = xlSheetVisible
Set shTemp = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
'Set the Array Values
ar = Array("CRN", "Customer Name", "Circuit/Equip ID", "Extension", "SLA", "Service Type", "Status")

For i = LBound(ar) To UBound(ar)
Set rng = shTemp.Rows(1).Find(ar(i), , xlValues).EntireColumn 'Loop through the Array
rng.Copy shAnal.Cells(1, i + 1)
Next
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler2

shAnal.Activate
shAnal.Columns.AutoFit
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Select
RefreshPivot ' Refresh the Pivot Tables
shTemp.Cells.ClearContents
shTemp.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler2:
MsgBox "Nothing to Analyse!"
shAnal.Activate
Range("A2:G2", Range("A2:G2").End(xlDown)).ClearContents ' Clears the contents of the Analyse sheet.
RefreshPivot 'Refresh the Pivot Tables
shTemp.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Sheets("Search").Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub
End Sub

Sub RenameColumnNames()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Temp").Visible = True

    On Error Resume Next
    'Column names in the "Temp" sheet can have two possible variants of the column names

    With Selection.Find(What:="Cct No/Eq ID", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlFormulas, lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext).Activate
    ActiveCell.Replace What:="Cct No/Eq ID", Replacement:="Circuit/Equip Id", _
        lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows
    End With

    With Selection.Find(What:="Customer", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Activate
    ActiveCell.Replace What:="Customer", Replacement:="Customer Name", lookat _
        :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows
      Range("A1").Select
    End With


    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Temp").Visible = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You are using `Find` to find the column headers to copy, which is good, so do the same for the destination sheet to find the right column for pasting.

Comment: With the current code I get Run-time error 91 on ```Set rng = shTemp.Rows(1).Find(ar(i), , xlValues).EntireColumn 'Loop through the Array```

Comment: Are you saying the code doesn't work as it stands? That error is probably because the item is not found.

Comment: I'm learning as I go, but I am still far off. The code I've used has been cobbled together and hopefully improved on from what I had before. I understand some of it, but wouldn't be able to sit and just write it with an idea. I've searched for examples that do parts of what I need, adapting, finding more, adapting again. So at this point I'm stumped. I had another spreadsheet today that had a simple bit of VBA code that does a query refresh and insert a timestamp give me an Object missing error that was not recoverable. I fortunately had a. Backup that I could use to rebuild it. Willing to try

Comment: May I ask please if you can show me where I'm going wrong with the code, I need to optimize this to run fast. This seems to be a slow method. Find a column copy and paste, next. Can the columns not be selected and copied in the specified order and pasted to the destination folder in one go? Or reorder the source columns with VBA? I have not looked into this option.
I have run into a problem with the formula that I want to be populated to the columns H:J where the reference remains on D2 on all the rows and not filled down with own reference row, the formula is displayed instead of working.

Comment: If the code works and you want to optimise this belongs on the Code Review site.

Comment: Hi SJR, thanks for the time. The code sort of works.

Comment: I can get it to copy from the source, if I arrange the columns in the app that I'm copying from to be in the right order, doesn't matter if there are other columns in between. The problem is, for the other people, that use this, that have not re-ordered their columns and are using the default order, it fails as well obviously the destination columns are not being found in any order and are being copied as is. I have read many hours of posts and watched tutorials to find a solution. Just can't figure it out. It's probably a simple solution.

Comment: I suggest you start again with a very specific question, reading [ask] and [mcve] before doing so.

Comment: Thanks. Will look into it. I have three new courses starting next week, so won't have much time to spend on this. But I think I may have a solution which ties in with your initial answer. Is it critical that I close this one or maybe just delete these chats? I would like to post what I have done if it works as I think it will, or create a new thread? Just have a lot on my plate at the moment. Where is Code Review?